# Testing a Windows 8 Store App with NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, nunit, windows-store-apps

I'm currently working on a Windows Store Application (Windows 8) for a class and I'm having problems getting my NUnit tests to run.

My Solution/Project setup looks like the following:

- TheMetroApp.sln

  - SQLite-net.csproj - Class Library (Windows Store Apps). Files are pulled from NuGet.
  - DataModel.csproj - Class Library (Windows Store Apps)
  - UnitTests.csproj - Unit Test Library (Windows Store Apps). NUnit framework is pulled from NuGet.
  - TheMetroApp.csproj - A project file which was pulled from one of the Windows SDK examples.
- Misc. Dependencies and Utilities

  - Windows 8 Pro RTM/Visual Studio 2012 RTM
  - ReSharper 7
  - NUnit 2.6.1
  - SQLite (Set up per the instructions [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx))

UnitTests is dependent upon and references DataModel. DataModel is dependent upon and references SQLite-net. The only thing I have added to the UnitTests project is a single class containing some stub NUnit unit tests. As far as I can tell, these are set up correctly:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TaskSourceTests
{
    #region Private Class Members

    private ITaskSource _taskSource;
    private String _dbPath;

    #endregion

    #region Testing Infrastructure

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // This part makes NUnit/ReSharper have problems.
        _dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "UnitTestDatabase.sqlite");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Misc. CRUD stuff

    [Test]
    public void CreateTaskTest()
    {
        // Save the task.
        Task task = new Task( "Some Task", "lol.", DateTime.Now, false );
        _taskSource.Save( task );

        // Confirm that it is in the task db.
        using( SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection( _dbPath ) )
        {
            const String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Id = ?";
            IList<Task> results = db.Query<Task>( query, task.Id );
            Assert.True( results.Contains( task ) );
        }
    }

    // ...and so on [but with stubs that are basically Assert.Fail( "" )].

    #endregion
}
```

TheMetroApp is one of the Windows 8 SDK sample projects, but with some custom XAML forms thrown in. I'm not having any problems with this project.

*My issue is that none of the Unit Test runners that I have tried to use are working.*

When I try to use the official NUnit x86 Test runner (version 2.6.1), my tests fail due to certificate related issues [(see here)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/449635cd-6aad-4d89-95a7-be7444d48f98):

```
UnitTests.TaskSourceTests.CreateTaskTest:
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)
```

ReSharper's NUnit test runner fails for the exact same reason. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is currently a workaround for that.

I have also tried using the test runner built into Visual Studio 2012 (through the [NUnit Visual Studio Test Adapter](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6)). When I try to run my tests using "Run All", I get the following output:

```
------ Run test started ------
Updating the layout...

Checking whether required frameworks are installed...

Registering the application to run from layout...

Deployment complete. Full package name: "GibberishAndStuff"

No test is available in C:\Projects\project-name\ProjectName\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:09.4873768) ==========
```

Something strange I have noticed is that if I select a specific test in the Test Explorer and tell it to run, I get a slightly different error message:

```
Could not find test executor with URI 'executor://nunittestexecutor/'.  Make sure that the test executor is installed and supports .net runtime version 4.0.30319.18010.
```

This is kind of perplexing because I have the NUnit Test Adapter installed. I'm not seeing anything similar to my issue on the launchpad page for the test adapter.

I'm not really sure where I should proceed from here. If this doesn't work I don't mind reworking my project to use xUnit.net, Microsoft's unit testing framework or something else. It would be pretty awesome if I could get NUnit working though.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question. I assume this because of the incompatibility of the reflection model with .NETCore with classic .NET. Also not sure if it's possible to load .NETCore apps in to Windows Desktop mode. This post explains the  differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have a Windows 7 Phone app which had the same issue that you have.  My solution was to create a separate "linked" project which compiles the code using the standard .net libraries.  The linked project will have no issues with unit test / NUnit.

See the following for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921109(v=pandp.40).aspx

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e730577-d11c-4f2e-8e2b-cbb87f76c044/

I've ported the app to Windows 8 and have no problems running my test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit the same error message while creating unit tests for an Universal App (W81 + WP81). The only solution here was to stop using NUnit and use MSTest only.