# Any free way to run NUnit tests from VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I am trying to find some free way to run NUnit tests from VS2013. I tried the [NUnit test adapter (both VSIX and NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/), but it doesn't seem to work (there the tests appear in the Test Explorer but are all grayed-out and can't be run). Is there something I need to do to get around this error/is there another extension out there that does this?

I am using NUnit 2.6.3.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework/ ?

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh: that claims to install NUnit 2.6.2. I already use 2.6.3. I don't have the ability to downgrade at this point. Is it worth installing anyway?

Comment: ah right, it won't be worth installing, not sure why it's not running your tests

Comment: There is also an *NUnitTestAdapter* without the framework [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/). Have you tried this?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: yes, that's the one I tried and couldn't get to work with VS2013

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run these tests for a Windows 8 application? It appears to be incompatible - or at least was when I last tried - I posted a similar thread as I was running into the same problem, and the posted solution did not work for me as I had a mix of W8 and older class libraries: [Windows 8 App in Visual Studio 2012 - NUnit Test Adapter sees unit tests but does not run them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871222/windows-8-app-in-visual-studio-2012-nunit-test-adapter-sees-unit-tests-but-doe)

Comment: this is a normal console app built and running on Windows 8. Also, can you convert this to a comment? It doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment on posts that aren't mine because I don't have 50 reputation, so if I want to contribute I'm forced to do it this way. I thought it might have answered you question in the event you were using the same type of application as I was, apologies.